# DDD-Aggregate Root / Does my inner entity need a local identity in this case?

Tags: architecture, entity, domain-driven-design, aggregate

Let's assume:

- a `User` entity as **aggregate root**. (containing *login*, *password*)
- a `UserProfile` entity as an inner part of `User`. (containing *lastName*, *firstName* etc..)

One reason of this separation is to keep SRP (separation of concerns):
`User` => deals with authentication data, `UserProfile` => deals with user's contact information etc..

I didn't choose to make `UserProfile` a linked and distinct aggregate root, since logically, a `UserProfile` without a linked `User` makes strictly no sense. Thus, we talk about a `composition` in UML sense.

Rules say that any client shouldn't access directly the aggregate root's inner entities.
Thus, no client should need to know the `UserProfile` identity to achieve their tasks. All that matters is the `User` one.
If someone wants to update the associated `UserProfile`, a method within `User` should be exist to this purpose.

Of course, my User entity needs an UUID (generated one as advised by **IDDD** book of Vaughn Vernon).
So I generated one using a dedicated library (Apache since I use JVM).

My question is focused on the associated `UserProfile` identity.
Since it makes no sense to expect it to be reachable outside; as **Evans** recommended, we should set a **"simple" local identity**, unique only within the concerned aggregate.

At first glance, it would be interesting for 1-N relationship:
One `User` containing MULTIPLE `UserProfile`. Those local identities would then allow to retrieve the right `UserProfile`(s), according to the use case.

But in case of **1-1 relationship** (one `User` HAS only one `UserProfile`), I even doubt about the necessity of an "identity", whatever there would be.

How should I tackle this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you said, if there is only a single `UserProfile` per `User` then there is no need for it to have an explicit local identity. In a scenario with multiple `UserProfile` value objects per `User` you'd need a way to reference specific profiles if you wanted to update them, for example.